# Validating and changing date format

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have been reading about how PHP interprets dates, especially when using a `/` or `-`.  As such, this has left me slightly confused.  I am reading in a CSV file, and converting it to an array.  My array, `csvData`, has the following data structure.

```
0 => array:3 [
    "ID" => "10338"
    "Date" => "19/08/2011"
    "Value" => "30"
]
```

So each array element contains an `ID`, `Date` and `Value`.  For now, I am concentrating on the Date element, which I can access like so

```
foreach ($this->csvData as $rowIndex => $csvValues) {
    var_dump($csvValues[$this->dateCol]);
}
```

This is the part I am unsure off.  I need to validate this date, and make sure it is in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`.  I have no idea what format the date might be in originally, it could literally be anything. It could be American format, I have even seen some like `2010-04-10T00:00:00Z` for instance.

The overall aim is to try and detect the format (maybe) and then convert it to the required format.  Additionally, if the date is in a completely illegible format, or empty for instance, I want to remove the whole element from the array.  This part should be straight forward though.

My main question for now is what would be the best way to process the date and then convert it into the correct format?  I have tried `strtotime` but when I outputted the value, it returned false.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTime class can handle almost any date format. It will fit your purposed. The [DateTime class constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) takes a `$string`, the date and  `$timezone`. You aren't worried about time just date so you should be fine.

```
    foreach ($this->csvData as $rowIndex => $csvValues) {

        //datetime class will parse that string into something php can understand
        $datetime = new DateTime($csvValues[$this->dateCol]);

        //you might have to look into the correct parameters here for the format you want
        $formatted_date = $datetime->format('d/m/Y')
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to check if the parsing is valid, and if not, remove the entire array element?

Comment: yes you can wrap the $datetime assignment in a try catch block and catch the exception for when its a bad date or you can change to procedural style and use date_create and date_format instead of new DateTime(). date_create returns false if it can't parse the date. So you will need to add an if statement and then just unset the array index with unset(csvData[$rowIndex]). Let me know if you need some help implementing.